# Mimik Smart-car-use-case -- Postman Simulation

Tags: postman, edgeengine

I am trying to solve the smart-car solution, I have a situation as below

- Device 1 and Device 2 are **Raspberry Pi OS device**
- Device 1 captured an image using the camera attached to it, and Device 2 finds the Device 1 and should be capable to view the captured image generated by the Device 1.

In the above situation since both the devices are taken as Raspberry Pi OS device,

**1.** **In which device should I download Postman and its associated collection and environment?**

I tried to install postman in one of the **Raspberry Pi OS devices**, but got some error as below.

[image]

**2. Since it showed some support/stable issue, Is there any other Pi image that is compatible with **Postman?****

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at official documentation from postman to get their recommendation on which image to use that is stable.